# Where do the new 2-blocks spawn in the 2048 game?

Tags: 2048

In the [2048 game](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) each move causes a new `2`-block to spawn. However, I couldn't figure out the logic behind *where* that block spawns. Is it random? Does it depend on the direction of your last move?

Comment: @TheifMaster I took a look at Manishearth's link and it turns out that [10% of the time 4-blocks also spawn](https://github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048/blob/master/js/game_manager.js#L71)!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's randomly chosen out of the available cells, as seen in the code [here](https://github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048/blob/master/js/grid.js#L25):

```
if (cells.length) 
{ 
    return cells[Math.floor(Math.random() * cells.length)];
}
```

(which is used [here](https://github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048/blob/db0dc7eae1af7a4bccd186c5933ae019635b3bc1/js/game_manager.js#L63) and eventually [here](https://github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048/blob/db0dc7eae1af7a4bccd186c5933ae019635b3bc1/js/game_manager.js#L156))